# Как ПРАВИЛЬНЕЕ создавать разные виды однотипных ячеек таблицы. Например newsfeed vk

Tags: swift, uitableview, xib

Я привык создавать ячейки с помощью xib. И вот для создания например новостной ленты vk приходится создавать много различных типов ячеек:

- ячейка с текстом и картинкой
- ячейка с текстом и collectionView
- ячейка просто с картинкой
- ячейка с видео
- ячейка с опросом и тд.

Создавать для каждого типа свой xib не логично. 
Можно наполнять ячейку кодом. Но хотелось бы использовать xib. Есть ли какая то возможность создать одну ячейку со всеми вариантами наполнения, а потом ненужные не показывать просто. Или использовать например stackView. Кто как делает??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Использовать xib-ы правильно, как и формировать ячейку через код.
Вы конечно можете создать один xib и "засунуть" в него все элементы (и скрывать ненужные), но это плохая практика, и она приведет к большой сложности изменений. При работе в команде это вообще парализует совместную работу.

Оптимальный вариант - для каждого типа ячейки свой xib или отдельные классы для построения ячейки через код.